# Doing a commit at the end of a process using executeUpdate command deleting multiple records

Tags: hibernate, execute

I am working on a process that takes on average about 200,000 records, summarizes the amounts, and adds them back to a table under a different post period key value on the same table.  And then cleans up the 200,000 records before that.   When I tried doing a hibernateSession.delete for each record it runs very slowly as compared to inserting close to the same number of records using hibernateSession.save.   So I was going to use a executeUpdate() statement to just delete them all at once.  While that significantly cuts down the time on the delete process, right now it seems that it automatically commits the changes.  If the hibernate.save or anything else after the delete abends, I lose the data.

My question is can I somehow "delay" the commits that happen during a executeUpdate.  Or somehow connect this to my HibernateSession and then it will commit when instructed

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When executing a query with `executeUpdate` all pending inserts/updates will be flushed which is probably what you are referring to as "committing"? I don't see how this is an issue though. Just defer the `executeUpdate` call.